# How do you add Honeycomb.io logging to an ASP.NET Core 7.0 application?

Tags: asp.net-core-7.0

I'm trying to add Honeycomb.io logging to my ASP.NET Core 7.0 application, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to add it to my application by following [the instructions in their setup guide](https://ui.honeycomb.io/airborn.co/environments/test/send-data#).

The instructions say "Then pass the `IConfiguration` object to configure the OpenTelemetry SDK in your application startup code:" and include a code example that has just a using statement and some C# instructions that aren't in a method.

I find this confusing and don't know how to add this to my `Startup.cs` or `Program.cs`. [Related but separate bonus question: can I use env vars to store the Honeycomb key on Heroku?]

Thanks!

Here is a link to [my Program.cs](https://ui.honeycomb.io/airborn.co/environments/test/send-data#) , I just can't figure out how to in incorporate the Honeycomb code into this.

Answer (score 1):

***Caveat:** I'm a DevRel at Honeycomb.*

There's a couple of things to unpack here, so I apologise if I go off track. Do keep in mind that you can ask this questions on our Honeycomb slack too.

The `IConfiguration` object is available from the ApplicationBuilder, if you're using minimal APIs, something like `builder.Configuration` will get you it, without seeing what your application startup looks, and what type of application it's hard to be more specific. `Configuration` or `IConfiguration` is a core part of .NET Core (now just .NET), so you should be able to find advice more generically on how to find that to pass it in.

There's also the question of whether you're looking at Tracing, or Logging as the examples we provide are around Tracing due to the OpenTelemetry logging specifications being not fully released.

You can absolutely provide the key via environment variables too, specifically either via the same mechanism that AppSettings uses in .NET, or via the specific ones the SDK looks for.

Here's a more full example: https://github.com/honeycombio/honeycomb-opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/examples/aspnetcore/Program.cs

You should also look at the OpenTelemetry docs which I've recently updated.  https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/net/getting-started/

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I added a link to my Program.cs - I also looked at your examples but they seem to use a new C# thing that I don't understand where you can have C# code that isn't in a method or class.

Comment: That's called TopLevel classes, that's just a combination of the old ConfigureServices and ConfigureAppBuilder methods, you should be able to split that up for an older version.